# Winston logger.info is not a function

Tags: node.js, logging, winston

I've set up Winston with transports to MySQL and console and put it in a module called `logger`. Like so...

```
// modules/logger.js

/* require statements */

exports.logger = new (winston.Logger)({
    transports: [
        new winstonMysql(winstonMysqlConfig),
        new (winston.transports.Console)
    ]
});
```

And then in `/modules`

```
// modules/index.js

/* grab other modules */

exports.logger = require('./logger.js');
```

When I do `console.log(modules.logger)`, I get this

```
{ logger: 
    EventEmitter {
        ...
        error: [Function],
        warn: [Function],
        info: [Function],
        verbose: [Function],
        debug: [Function],
        silly: [Function],
        ...
    }
 }
```

But when I call `modules.logger.info()` it throws `modules.logger.info is not a function` error. What's wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You aren't exporting the logger properly in `modules.js`.

```
exports.logger = require('./logger.js').logger;
```

Answer (score 4):

I have also faced similar issues, but my directory structure is somewhat different I have a logger file and import are a little different here is how I have fixed using the above reference

```
const winston = require('winston');

const logConfiguration = {
    format: winston.format.json(),
    'transports': [
        new winston.transports.Console(),
        new winston.transports.File({
            filename: 'sample.log'
        })
    ]
};


const logger = winston.createLogger(logConfiguration);

exports.logger = logger;
```

Import

```
...

const logger = require('../logger/app-logger').logger
logger.info({type: 'login', user: user.name});
...
```